# Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Error 13 initializing the Gpio driver

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

Using: .NET 6 console app, published and deployed to: Raspberry PI: Model Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4 (Ubuntu 20.04)

When I run the command:  `dotnet CardSystem.dll`
I get the following error: Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Error 13 initializing the Gpio driver. The error happens on `controller.OpenPin(pin, PinMode.Output);`

```
using System.Device.Gpio;
 
       private static void Call(int pin)
        {
            using (GpioController controller = new GpioController())
            {
                controller.OpenPin(pin, PinMode.Output);
                controller.Write(pin, PinValue.High);
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Access to GPIO often requires elevated permissions (or explicitly configuring things to grant the necessary access to whichever account you're using to run the code). If you run your dotnet code as `root`, does it work? It's probably just a permissions issue.

Comment: I tried "sudo dotnet CardReaderSystem.dll" and got error
sudo: dotnet: command not found

Comment: So the `dotnet` command is installed somewhere that's not in the default `$PATH`. You could try `sudo $(which dotnet) CardReaderSystem.dll` and see what that gets you.

Comment: That command did work. My console app ran and I saw the Console.WriteLine that i added to help me see logic.